# Buffered (infinite) grid with buffered store does not update on store reload

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

We have a simple setup of a grid feeded by a buffered store. But if we call `reload()` on the store the store reloads but the grid didn't update. If we call `load()` the all is updated. We want to call reload because we want to keep all sorters, groupers & filters.

**Here is the store**

```
Ext.define('App.store.User',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.Direct'],
    model: 'App.model.User',

    remoteGroup: true,

    autoLoad: true,
    buffered: true,
    pageSize: 50,
    leadingBufferZone: 500,
    trailingBufferZone: 500,
    autoSync: true,

    constructor: function(config) {
        config = Ext.apply({}, config);
        if (!config.proxy) {
            var proxy = {
                type: 'direct',
                reader: {
                    idProperty: 'Id',
                    root: 'data',
                    type: 'json'
                },
                writer: {
                    allowSingle: false
                },
                api: {
                    read: User.List, 
                    create: User.Create,
                    update: User.Update,
                    destroy: User.Delete
                }
            };
            config.proxy = proxy;
        }

        this.callParent([config]);
    }
);
```

**And the grid**

```
Ext.define('App.view.grid.User',{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.usergrid',

    id: 'user-grid',

    loadMask: true,

    selModel: {
        multiSelect: true,
        pruneRemoved: false
    },
    selType: 'checkboxmodel',
    multiSelect: true,
    viewConfig: {
        trackOver: false
    },
    plugins:[{
        ptype: 'bufferedrenderer',
        trailingBufferZone: 50,
        leadingBufferZone: 50
    }],

    features:[{
        ftype: 'grouping',
        enableGroupingMenu: false
    }],

    constructor: function(config) {
        var editor = {ptype:'rowediting', clicksToEdit: 2};
        config = Ext.apply({}, config);
        if (!config.plugins) {
            config.plugins = [editor];
        } else {
            if(Ext.isArray()) {
                config.plugins.push(editor);
            } else {
                config.plugins = [config.plugins,editor];
            }
        }
        config.store = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('User');
        this.callParent([config]);
    },

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        if (!me.store) {
            me.store = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('User');
        }

        me.columns = [
            {text: 'ID',dataIndex:'Id'},
            {text: 'Client-ID',dataIndex:'Client_id'},
            {text: 'SuperiorId',dataIndex:'Superior_id'},
            {text: 'LastChange',dataIndex:'LastChange',xtype:'datecolumn',format:'d.m.Y'},
            {text: 'UserName',dataIndex:'UserName',editor:{xtype:'textfield'}},
            {text: 'Firstname',dataIndex:'Firstname',editor:{xtype:'textfield'}},
            {text: 'Lastname',dataIndex:'Lastname',editor:{xtype:'textfield'}},
            {text: 'ShortName',dataIndex:'ShortName',editor:{xtype:'textfield'}}
        ];

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: Where is it that you're calling reload or load?

Comment: @incutonez I think it doesn't matter from where I call, because the store reloads (and the grid shows the load mask). But the changes only get rendered if I call `load()` instead of `reload()`. But that dumps all applied filters, sorts & groups

Comment: ok, if you say so.  I was just hoping for a working example, as that's much easier to work with.  Hope you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, my filters weren't applied, after reload can you try.

```
grid.getStore().loadPage(grid.getStore().currentPage);
```